# Hyperledger: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

all,

I was able to install and run Hyperledger Fabric v 1.0 and Hyperledger Composer but I could not seem to be able to run composer-rest-service in an Ubuntu VM with the following error:

```
Connection fails: Error: Error trying login and get user Context. 
Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. 
Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
```

This happens when I try to deploy a new business network using composer-playground with Connection: hlfv1 (and not Connection: Web Browser)

I used the following configuration:
[image]

May I know what I am possibly doing wrong?

Enrollment ID is: admin
Enrollment Secret is: password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the default Development Fabric which is started with the script `startFabric.sh` then the default Enrollment ID is admin, and the Secret is adminpw.

If you have setup your own custom fabric and CA you may have different defaults.  But the error is indicating a problem with the ID and Secret.